# linear independence , matrix notation question.

Tags: linear-algebra

My problem is quite trivial.I have the vectors

$(1,0,0,1),(2,3,-3,9),(1,3,-4,7),(2,0,1,3)$ and
it's easy to see that summing up the first two vectors we get the sum of the last two. So the vectors are linear dependent.

I also wanted to check the result in Matrix notation.But putting the vectors as column vectros in a Matrix $A$ and solving $Ax=0$ via Gauss elimination, I get $x=(0,0,0,0)$. But i should get $x=(1,1,-1,-1)$. I hope I'm doing something wrong in the calculation and it's not a theorical misunderstanding (I'm very tired too at the moment).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Ax=0$ always has the trivial solution $x=0$. The point is that if it has any other solution the vectors formed by the columns are linearly dependent.

Comment: that's the point. Trough Gauss elimination i get $x=(0,0,0,0)$ as the $\bf only$ solution.

Comment: So i must have made a error in the calculations...

Comment: You must, I just calculated the determinant of the matrix. It's 0.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. Sometimes I loose  myself in the calculations to the point of doubting even the most certain theoretical knowledge i have...sorry.

Comment: happens to me too.